# Copy pasting dynamic data through Google Apps Script or Formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good morning,

I am using the following script right now to get the following situation: For a lead list which is dynamic so constantly moves, we want to extract certain information if they fall in a specific category. "C-Grade"

Essentially all data from all "C Grade" rated people, need to be copied from "Data info" onto "Lead info"

Normally I would use `=vlookup`
but since its dynamic and constantly changing, I don't see the option to use a formula.

App Script I am using right now:

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data info");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lead info");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(1,12);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,2,12,2);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);

  // clear source values
  source.clearContent();
}
```

Here is the example file: [Example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H73rgHf5uQ5jZ546noefm6wNhazgYdvIY3o0ZhqYyxk/edit#gid=1342751544)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the rows which have the value of `C Grade` in the column "D" of "Data info" sheet to "Lead info" sheet.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function copyInfo() {
  var check = "C Grade"; // This is from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data info");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lead info");
  var values = copySheet.getRange("A2:D" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[3] == check);
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When I saw your script, the value of "L1" of "Data info" is copied to "B1:C12" of "Lead info". When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, "L1" of "Data info" has no value.
- In this modification, the values of "Data info" are retrieved and filtered by "C Grade" of the column "D", and the filtered values are put to "Lead info" sheet.

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

### Added 1:

When I saw your provided sample Spreadsheet again, I noticed that your script has been changed. And, I noticed that 2 points are different from your initial sample Spreadsheet.

1. In your initial Spreadsheet, "ABC Grade" was column "D". But, in your current Spreadsheet, that is colum "E".
2. In my proposed script, I proposed `var values = copySheet.getRange("A2:D" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[3] == check);`. But in your current script, that is changed to `var values = copySheet.getRange("A1:D10" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[0] == check);`/

I think that the reason for your current issue is that you changed your initial Spreadsheet and my proposed script. When your current Spreadsheet is used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function copyInfo() {
  var check = "C Grade"; // This is from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data info");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lead info");
  var values = copySheet.getRange("A1:E" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[4] == check);
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When `values` has no value, an error occurs. So, I added `if (values.length == 0) return;`.

### Added 2:

From your following new 2nd question,

> Would there also be a way to only get certain colums. In this case A,B,D & E.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function copyInfo() {
  var check = "C Grade"; // This is from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data info");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lead info");
  var values = copySheet.getRange("A1:E" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[4] == check).map(r => [1, 2, 4, 5].map(e => r[e - 1]));
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tanaike for this Modification. I only seem to be getting an error now when running the script.

length is missing information. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
copyInfo @ Code.gs:8"

Should I not run the script or?

Comment: @Scraper2022 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined copyInfo @ Code.gs:8`, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script using your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurs. I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this again. I'm worried that you are using a different Spreadsheet or you miscopied my proposed script. How about this? Please test my proposed script using your provided Spreadsheet, again.

Comment: I tried to do this and double checked both the script and the file. Nothing changed.

I found this on Google "The simplest fix to this error is to make sure we are defining what we want to compare length to, so we need to make certain we are passing in an argument when we invoke the function inside of our console.log.".

But looking at the code, I am not sure what length is being compared to.

Comment: @Scraper2022 Thank you for replying. About `I tried to do this and double checked both the script and the file. Nothing changed.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script using your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurs again. So, in order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet and your current script for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H73rgHf5uQ5jZ546noefm6wNhazgYdvIY3o0ZhqYyxk/edit#gid=1080220666

And Script: 


**function copyInfo() {
  var check = "C Grade"; // This is from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data info");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lead info");
  var values = copySheet.getRange("A1:D" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[3] == check);
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}**

Comment: @Scraper2022 By checking your current Spreadsheet, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? This added script is used for your current Spreadsheet. If you changed the Spreadsheet again, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: It works! Thank you, I appreciate it. Would there also be a way to only get certain colums. In this case A,B,D & E.

Comment: @Scraper2022 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `It works! Thank you, I appreciate it. Would there also be a way to only get certain colums. In this case A,B,D & E.`, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Scraper2022 I have already understood that your 1st question was resolved. About your 2nd question, can I ask you whether your 2nd question was also resolved?

Comment: @Scraper2022 Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.